Oracle Field Services Cloud Simple Plugin
I've signed up for the task of developing hosted plugins for OFSC. My background is in Angular - from JS to 17 w/ Node.
I've become familiar with JET 11 (the version the instance uses) and the existing hosted plugins. I've had success editing existing plugins and duplicating to modify for a sikmilar use, however they are copies of copies cluttered with artifacts and undocumented. I'd like to start with a clean slate.
Recently I created a very simple Hello World plugin to console log the Open data in Angular. I ran ng build and created the zip containing index.html, main.js, polyfills.js and a styles.css.
There was no error when it was uploaded to the plugin settings page, however when I launched the plugin via button, the js and css files were returning 404s and the plugin failed to load. All 4 files were in the same directory level of the zip file and the html referenced the files like so:
<script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>

Inspecting the plugin showed me the sctipt files were attempting to be found at the root of the server (https://INSTANCENAME.test.fs.ocs.oraclecloud.com/) instead of the plugin path where the index.html lived.
I can't see why the script and css files got lost.
Is there an approach to creating a simple html/js/css plugin without require and the other libraries I found in the existing complex plugins? All I am trying to do is console.log the init and open data…
I'd appreciate any insight as finding a difinitive approach that is simple. I've seen the git repos and this page: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/field-service/fapcf/index.html#id0894FK005PF but I find the details lacking...

https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#html5-urls-and-the-base-href

Of course. Sometimes you miss the basics after not setting up a fresh app in a while.
